# How can I store the url of a popup window into a string?

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension

I am currenttly developing a Chrome extension and i would like to store the url of a popup window into a string variable.
I am able to get the url via the "`document.createElement` and `variable.appendChild` methods, but I can't store it in a string.

This works :

```
    function getLinks(){
  var url = document.createElement("p");

  chrome.tabs.query({windowType:"popup"}, function (tab){
    for(x in tab){
       var adresse= document.createTextNode(tab[x].url);
       url.appendChild(adresse);
    }  
  });
  document.body.appendChild(url);
}
```

This does not work :

```
function getLinksbis(){
  var url = "1 - ";

  chrome.tabs.query({windowType:"popup"}, function (tab){
    for(x in tab){
       var adresse= tab[x].url;
       url = url + adresse;
    }  
  });
  document.write(url);
}
```

Can you help me ? Is it possible to do what i want ?
I want it in a string because I want to add parameters to this url and then shoot it back to the user.

Please excuse my english, I'm french. ;-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work, just ensure you have

```
{
  ..
  "permissions":["tabs"]
  ..
}
```

tabs permission in your manifest file.

## Output taken after testing

[image]

## EDIT 1

```
function getLinksbis() {
    var url = "1 - ";

    chrome.tabs.query({
        windowType: "popup"
    }, function (tab) {
        for (x in tab) {
            var adresse = tab[x].url;
            url = url + adresse;
        }
        document.write(url);
    });

}
```

Move your `document.write(url);` inside async call back, it is an asynchronous function and final call should be taken after call back is successful.

Comment: Hi. Yes, the first function works just fine, but the other does not. In the first i have a "<p>" with the url inside, but i want it in a string so that i can add parameters in it after. And yes, i do have have the "tabs" permission in my manifest. ;-)

Comment: So how come the first function does return the url and the second returns "1 - " when it should return "1 - url" if it were working ?

Comment: @user1986474:Check my `edit1` it should solve your problem, it is async nature of chrome

Comment: :it does work, thank you very much ! But when i click on the link that i have created, nothing happens... New problem but it's ok, I will look into it, thanks again for your time.